# Troubles with covariance comprehension in generics

Tags: c#, generics

I'm facing an implementation problem when trying to enqueue two different instances of a generic class into one queue:

```
var transactionsWorker = new FetchLinesWorker<TransactionLine, UnsoldLine>(new UnsoldLineWrapper(), new FilteredTransactionLines());
var ordersWorker = new FetchLinesWorker<OrderLineDeliveryGood, UnsoldLine>(new UnsoldDeliveryLineWrapper(), new FilteredOrderLines());
var workerQueue = new Queue<FetchLinesWorker<object, UnsoldLine>>();
workerQueue.Enqueue(transactionsWorker);
workerQueue.Enqueue(ordersWorker);
new WorkerForm(workerQueue, () => whenFetchingFinished(workerQueue.SelectMany(w => w.Result))).StartJob();
```

The two last lines don't compile because it says `cannot convert from FetchLinesWorker<XXXLine, UnsoldLine> to FetchLinesWorker<object, UnsoldLine>`.

I thought that C# was supporting covariance for generics but it looks like it is not the case. Then why is the compiler complaining about that ?

---

As requested below is more code to help in locating context:

```
public interface IWrapperLine<In, Out>
{
    Out Convert(In input);
}

public class FetchLinesWorker<In, Out> : JobWorker
{
    private readonly IQueryable<In> _inputs;
    private readonly IWrapperLine<In, Out> _converter;

    public FetchLinesWorker(IWrapperLine<In, Out> converter, IQueryable<In> inputs) : base(0, TranslationsHelper.GetEntityProgressMessage(typeof(In)))
    {
        _inputs = inputs;
        _converter = converter;
        DoWork += SoldStatisticLinesWorker_DoWork;
    }

    private void SoldStatisticLinesWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Result.Clear();
        ProgressMax = _inputs.Count();
        foreach (var input in _inputs)
        {
            Result.Add(_converter.Convert(input));
            DoProgress();
        }
    }

    public List<Out> Result { get; } = new List<Out>();
}

public class FilteredTransactionLines : IQueryable<TransactionLine> { ... }

public class FilteredOrderLines : IQueryable<OrderLineDeliveryGood> { ... }

public class WorkerForm
{
    public WorkerForm(Queue<JobWorker> workers, Action finishedAction) { ...}
}
```

`JobWorker` inherits from `BackgroundWorker` but I can't edit this class.

Note: coming from a Java background, I would have declared the queue like that. Is there an equivalent in C# ?

```
var workerQueue = new Queue<FetchLinesWorker<?, UnsoldLine>>();
```

Comment: Yes, C# supports generic type variance. But, you have to use it correctly. For one, it applies to _interfaces_ not classes. For another, your usage has to be type-safe; the code you posted may or not be, but we can't know because you haven't provided sufficient context.

Comment: You are using `object`, not a parent type or interface. You are actually trying to *erase* the type of the contents, not use covariance

Comment: C# only supports covariance on generic interfaces and delegates, not classes. [See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). Under the hood, the implementation of generics is wildly different between .NET and Java, which is why things like Java's wildcard `?` aren't supported.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I provided more code, I hope enough to have a sufficient context. I fear I can't use an interface because I need at least a `Queue<FetchLinesWorker<,>>` to be able to do `w.Result` without downcasting.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `object` is the only common ancestor between these two types.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think I will have troubles to use an interface (see my comment to PeterDuniho above). But thank you for the link.

Answer (score 3):

In C# you need to define [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) explicitly, and this can only be done using interfaces. To get your code to compile, you'll need to introduce an interface:

```
public interface IFetchLinesWorker<out T, U>
{
    List<U> Result { get; }

    ...
}

public class FetchLinesWorker<T, U> : IFetchLinesWorker<T, U>
{
    ...
}
```

and change your code to:

```
IFetchLinesWorker<TransactionLine, UnsoldLine> transactionsWorker =
    new FetchLinesWorker<TransactionLine, UnsoldLine>();
IFetchLinesWorker<OrderLineDeliveryGood, UnsoldLine> ordersWorker =
    new FetchLinesWorker<OrderLineDeliveryGood, UnsoldLine>();
var workerQueue = new Queue<IFetchLinesWorker<object, UnsoldLine>>();
workerQueue.Enqueue(transactionsWorker);
workerQueue.Enqueue(ordersWorker);
```

Comment: Better yet, use an interface instead of `object`

Comment: I have provided more code. You solution works for my initial problem, however with that I encounter a problem on the line `new WorkerForm(workerQueue, () => whenFetchingFinished(workerQueue.SelectMany(w => w.Result))).StartJob();` because now I can't access `w.Result` anymore without downcasting.

Comment: @Spotted, adding the 'Result' property to the 'IFetchLinesWorker' interface definition will fix your problem. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I agree but wanted to keep the answer in line with the question :-)

Comment: I know but when declaring `var workerQueue = new Queue<IFetchLinesWorker<object, UnsoldLine>>();` the line `new WorkerForm(workerQueue, () => whenFetchingFinished(workerQueue.SelectMany(w => w.Result))).StartJob();` does not compile because it is expected a `Queue<JobWorker>` as first argument

Comment: @Spotted, have the `WorkerForm ` constructor accept `Queue<IFetchLinesWorker<object,UnsoldLine>>` could be a solution. However, it depends on your architecture whether this is a viable one in your case. Introducing an interface (`IJobWorker`) could also help. In my opinion, in general, providing a `Queue` of interfaces (i.e. `Queue<IJobWorker>`) is to be preferred over providing a `Queue` of (abstract) classes (as you do now).

Comment: Totally agree with you, I will keep your advice as a best practice. However `WorkerForm` is not a class of mine and I'm not sure it can be changed... :-(

Comment: I'm also seeing that `JobWorker` inherits from `BackgroundWorker`. Thus introducing an `Queue<IJobWorker>` in `WorkerForm` would totally break it and introduce a big refactor because some methods from `BackgroundWorker` used in `WorkerForm` would suddenly be unavailable.

Comment: Would creating a `Queue<JobWorker>` instead of a `Queue<IFetchLinesWorker<object, UnsoldLine>>` work? I.e.:

`var workerQueue = new Queue<JobWorker>();`

This could also render the need for covariance obsolete.